# Navigation Drawer Activity change fragment from external button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

So I have set up the default Navigation Drawer Activity in Android Studio. I also added some buttons in the default navigation activity XML. The default navigation menu buttons obviously change the fragment, but I was wondering how I could also change the fragments via the buttons that I have added along the bottom? The reason I am having trouble is that the default nagivation menu buttons are part of a navGraph, whereas my buttons are not, thanks!

[[image]][[image]][image]

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: allow the buttons I have placed along the bottom change the fragment, just like the menu buttons on the side navigation pannel

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set `onClickListeners` on the button.

For example:

```kotlin
val postButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.post_button)

postButton.setOnClickListener {
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.post_fragment)
}
```